# Access current element and next element arraylist without getting out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So I have an ArrayList that want to make a HashMap of the occurrences of the pairs so B,C = 1 after running through ArrayList1 below. Then B,C after running through ArrayList2 would be B,C = 2

```
ArrayList1 = {A,B,C,D}
ArrayList2 = {D,B,C,A}
```

I was planning on using HashMap< String, HashMap< String,Integer >> so that key in parent hashmap would be B and the child key would be C so the pair B,C = 1 after running through ArrayList1. (Sorry if my terminology is wrong just what I'd call each key)

My issue is how would I access current and next element when looping through the ArrayList without getting a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {...}`?

Comment: You can make use of iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** i am getting you right you want to print out the no. of pairs in order like `AB - 1, BC - 2, CD - 1, DB - 1, CA - 1`. So for such a scenario i would propose a solution like:

```
lst = {A,B,C,D}
lst2 = {D,B,C,A}

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

for ArrayList1

```
for(int i = 0; i<lst.size()-1; i++) 
    // checking whether pair already exists
    if(map.containsKey(lst.get(i)+lst.get(i+1))) 
        map.put(lst.get(i)+lst.get(i+1), map.get(lst.get(i)+lst.get(i+1))+1); // if yes increment the current value by one
    else 
        // else add the new key with value 1
        map.put(lst.get(i)+lst.get(i+1), 1);
```

Similarly for ArrayList2

```
for(int i = 0; i<lst2.size()-1; i++) 
    // Checking for existing key in same map thus will increment any key matching that of lst keys or any in current lst2
    if(map.containsKey(lst2.get(i)+lst2.get(i+1)))
        map.put(lst2.get(i)+lst2.get(i+1), map.get(lst2.get(i)+lst2.get(i+1))+1);
    else
        map.put(lst2.get(i)+lst2.get(i+1), 1);
```

Thus printing the map

```
Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
    if(itr.hasNext())
        itr.forEachRemaining(new Consumer<Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            public void accept(Entry<String, Integer> t) {
                System.out.println(t.getKey() +" --> " + t.getValue());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop Arraylist in this way without any exception

```
for(String myVar : myArrayList){
     //your logic here
}
```

Comment: Yes you can but this will only get me the current item of the arraylist where  I need the current one and the next one. So for the 1st loop of the arraylist I would need element 0 and element 1